# Wordpress mails being sent from @locahost and being rejected

Tags: plugin-development, email, 500-internal-error

I'm having a weird issue with the email from name being set as @localhost when I send mails from a site. Im running on Nginx and PHP7.

Its consequently being rejected so I get a 500 on user registration.

I've tried setting the name, email address via functions.php, hardcoding the site urls in local-config, using SparkPost, turning off Cloudflare, confirming server name in nginx config and trying to do an ini_set in my local-config.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What is the setting in your server `/etc/hostname` file? Based on wp_mail source code:

```
if ( !isset( $from_email ) ) {
    // Get the site domain and get rid of www.
    $sitename = strtolower( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
    if ( substr( $sitename, 0, 4 ) == 'www.' ) {
        $sitename = substr( $sitename, 4 );
    }
    $from_email = 'wordpress@' . $sitename;
}
```

What this means is that the name `localhost` is pick up from `/etc/hostname`.